# Divide binary row and convert each part to float or decimal python 3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, loops, binary, converters

I am using python-3.x and I am trying to take each binary row in the [x] array and divided into two parts the first four digits will make the first number and the second four digits as the secund number after I convert them to floats.

there is a function "def test(binary)" that will do the convert from binary to floats, and there are two loops to go over the array.

for example, the first row is: [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
I want to divide it to 1001 - 1000
then the final result will be [9, 8]

```
import numpy as np
n = 4

##################################
# convert a list of Binary's to decimal
def test(binary):
    wordlength = binary.shape[1]
    shift = np.arange(wordlength-1, -1, -1)
    decimal = np.sum(binary << shift, 1)
    print (decimal)
##################################

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)


x = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
             [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
             [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]])

print(x)

for ii in range (3) :
    start_array = 0
    X = x[ii]
    print ("X:" '\n', X)
    #print(ii, X)

    for i in range (2) : 
        end_array= start_array  + n 
        print ("end_array:" '\n', end_array)
        print ("start_array:" '\n', start_array) 
        flot = np.zeros ((3, 2))
        flot[ii, i] = test(x[start_array:end_array])

        print (flot)
        start_array=end_array
```

but i couldn't get the right result I am not sure where is the problem, if my way to solve this problem is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a list of integers you could do this:

- Convert to a list of strings
- Concatenate using join
- Split the list in half
- Use int to convert to binary

In long form:

```
x = [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]
# The following two lines are equivalent - choose the most readable
strings = ''.join(map(str,x)) # Using map
strings = ''.join(str(z) for z in x) # Using a list loop
print(strings)
strings1 = strings[:4] # First four
strings2 = strings[-4:] # Last four
bin1 = int(strings1)
bin2 = int(strings2)
# int function takes a second argument for base
int1 = int(strings1,2)
int2 = int(strings2,2)
```

In one line:

```
int1 = int(''.join(map(str,x))[:4],2)
int2 = int(''.join(map(str,x))[-4:],2)
```

Fitting your question, which contains a list of lists:

```
# For each element l of list x (l being a list)
for l in x:
    for z in l:
        int1 = int(''.join(map(str,z))[:4],2)
        int2 = int(''.join(map(str,z))[-4:],2)
        print(int1)
        print(int2)
```

Comment: Thank your for a great way, but if I used the list of a numpy array "Binary's" I will get this error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '[1 0'` any idea @mjsqu

Comment: I tried this method before in another way, but I have the same error, that why I tried what I wrote in the beginning!!!!

Comment: Updated, it seems the numpy array might be an array of a list of lists, so I've added an extra `for` to the loop